# Is MySql capable of distributed transactions (off the box) like sql-server's **Begin Distributed Transaction**?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, distributed, distributed-transactions

Is MySql capable of distributed transactions?

Like (from a sql-server background) **Begin Distributed Transaction** ?

Comment: is it like autonomous transaction in oracle or firebird http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-psql-autonomous-trans.html ?

Comment: i'm not sure with the other databases, i only have experience with sql-server

Comment: @totsum: I haven't used it but check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xa.html

Comment: And this (old) presentation file: http://conferences.oreillynet.com/cs/mysqluc2005/view/e_sess/6281

Comment: @Hugues Van Landeghem: an automomous transaction is something completely different than a distributed transaction.